# How to make an external js file write to the html <script> tags? Via plain JS or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to write a function in an external javascript file linked to the index.html, which when called writes; for example between the `<script></script>` tags in the index.html file on line 18. Is it possible to do this with plain Javascript or jQuery? If so, how could this be done?

EDIT: I want to only have one script tag in my index.html.

```js
function writeToScriptTags() {
  // this function should write alert("Hello") to the <script></script> tags in the index.html file.
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!-- Dependencies -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/color/jquery.color-2.1.2.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <title>CodeDragon</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/master.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="Dragon"></div>

    <input type="text" name="_input" value="" id="_input">
    <script src="script.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script>
      // Javascript file should write alert("Hello") here
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the script tag already exists then you can set it's `text`/`textContent`/`innerText` value to whatever code you want to execute. But the script would need to have been empty beforehand, ie no text not even whitespace, otherwise it would not run.

```
//use an appropriate css selector to find the correct script
//this just selects the first script it finds
var s = document.querySelector('script');
s.text = 'alert("Here")';
```

It would probably be better to just create a new script element and add the code to that as then you would not need to worry about wither or not the script tag had already previously been used.

```
var s = document.createElement('script');
document.head.appendChild(s);
s.text = 'alert("Here")';
```

And of course if the script is set with a `src` attribute setting the text of the script will not run any code as it is ignored for externally linked script elements.

Comment: Hm yeah I had that thought as well, but the idea of always creating a new script tag and my app will probably have 100's of script tags and I assumed it would take up a lot of unecessary bytes to load. And I'm really not a fan of messy :| So with the average of a 100 <script></script> tags. A hundred of those tags would take 1.7kb's. Which is kinda okay then I guess, but the mesiness just hangs above my head :/ But, what you wrote works perfectly and it will do the job flawlessy and I can move on with my webapp/library now so thank you Patrick :-)

Comment: @Holiday why do you need to write so many? Why arent you just writing the code directly, ie right in your function? Also if your goal is to only have 1 script tag you can remove it before adding the next one. Removing a script doesn't affect anything as the code in it will have already been loaded into memory.

Comment: Because you are not directly writing the code, it's auto generated for you. I mustn't talk deeper about it. Removing the script tag kills the entire purpose of writing the script tag in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way
Say this is you external.js file

```
function writeToScriptTags() {
  // this function should write alert("Hello") to the <script></script> tags in the index.html file.
}
```

You can call functions of external.js file between the  tags in the index.html file this way.

```
$.getscript("path/to/jsFile", function() {
    writeToScriptTags()
});
```

Hope you can get an idea.

Comment: Think you misunderstood me as far as I can tell. I want external.js to be able to write custom functions into the <script></script> tags in the index.html. So that everything is in one file; the html, the css and the js. With this, the user only needs one file for his/hers website to work properly and doesn't need to think about anything else.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery solution:

```
$('script').html('alert(\'Hello\')');
```

Plain JS solution:

```
document.querySelector('html').innerHTML = alert('Hello');
```

Don't add it to the code as a text, beceause it'd be rendered as a plain text and it wouldn't have any functionality.